# How to create installer for suite with install4j?

Tags: install4j

We have a "suite" of two programs, much like Office has Word and Excel. We determine if the user needs program A or B o both based on some questions. We would like to have a common installer to ask this questions, and install common files, then download and install the individual programs accordingly.

Both programs have different update cycles, so we would like to check for updates per program and ideally also updates to the installer itself (for changes in the common files).

Which would be the best approach for this?

I have tried the individual programs to be downloadable components but this approach doesn't handle new version of just one program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 8.x, there is no special "suite of installers" feature in install4j. I would recommend to create a separate project for the suite and add the single installers to the distribution tree in separate downloadable installation component. Instead of the "Install files" action, add "Run executable" actions for each product that was selected by the user.

If you would like unattended installations for each product, you can pass the arguments

```
-q -splash "Installing product X"
```

to get a progress bar for each installer.

Comment: To clarify, I would have one installer for the suite, and one individual project for each program, and these are NOT merged projects,  correct? 
In a "Run executable" action I check which components were selected and execute them. I guess a different question, but in MacOs can a .dmg be mounted and executed via script?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, no merged projects are involved in this solution. You would use a "Extract a DMG file on macOS" action before executing the installer. This is easier than mounting the DMG and it's how the background update downloader does it.

Comment: Great ! Are there any caveats for running the .sh in linux?

Comment: No, this works just as well as executing an .exe on Windows

Comment: how could you deal with someone executing an old suite installer once there are  already new versions of the individual program installers (the components)?  Ideally I would want the suite installer to download the latest available version of the related installers.

Comment: You would have to code that check yourself using the ApplicationRegistry API, see the example in the code callery for checking installed application versions. With "Download file" actions you can download new installer files if the old ones are out of date. The up-to date versions can be retrieved with "Check for update" actions.

Comment: As I understand, the "Install files" action already downloads the components files. I need that action to install the other files of the distribution tree that are not my downloadable components. If i am downloading the components manually with "Check for update" and "Download file" actions, then in the "Install files" action I should use the File Filter script to avoid downloading out of date versions of those components, am I correct?

Comment: No, the file filter script works on already downloaded files. You cannot use the installation components in this case, you always have to download the most recent installer of each sub-product with an "Install files" action.